# StatsD-Exporter metrics are not being received from Java

Tags: java, docker, udp, metrics, statsd

I'm going thru [this](https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/custom-metrics-in-dataflow-pipelines-with-prometheus-and-statsd-9f37332f2992) tutorial on my Mac, trying to send counter metrics from my Java code to Prometheus via StatsD-Exporter.

On my localhost I run two Docker containers, one is Prometheus, the other is StatsD-exporter. Trying to be as much permitting as possible, this is my statsd_mapping.yaml:

```
mappings:
- match: "*.*.*.*"
  name: "${1}_name"
  labels:
    label1: "$2"
    label2: "$3"
    label3: "$4"
```

So in order to send some data to statsd-exporter, I'm using this shell command a few times:

```
echo -n 'blah.step_4.reason.new_entities:1|c' | nc -u -w0 localhost 9125
```

Then I'm browsing to `http://localhost:9102/metrics` and I can see my metric there:

```
# HELP blah_name Metric autogenerated by statsd_exporter.
# TYPE blah_name counter
blah_name{label1="step_4",label2="reason",label3="new_entities"} 5
```

My metric was received 5 times as expected.

Then I'm using the Java NonBlockingStatsDClient, sending the same metric, and I expect to see the metric as before.

This is my Java code:

```
private static final StatsDClient statsd = new NonBlockingStatsDClient(
        "",
        "127.0.0.1",                        
        9125          
);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    statsd.incrementCounter("blah1.step_4.reason.new_entities");
}
```

Running the code above bring random results.

- Sometimes I just cannot find my metric
- In most of the times I **can** find a new metric sent from Java but it is stuck on count 1. Means that even if I send the same metric 10 times, it'll still display 1. Then taking the same name of the metric and sending it to statsd from the shell - and the counter increments.

What do I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK I just got it solved.
The problem is that I'm using a **Non** blocking client. As the main thread is dead before the client succeeded to send anything - I couldn't find any metric on StatsD.